# Identify an internal wire connector on the original NES

Tags: connector, identification

I am trying to identify a wire connector used on the main board of the original NES(Nintendo Entertainment System). I have been successful in identifying other connectors using online resources, but this one has me stumped. Other online forums(including NES dedicated ones) have been unable to help. One primary problem is identifying the manufacturer as there is only a single letter and an obscure logo.

The connector is identified as P6 on the main board.

Info I have:

- 5 pins - keyed with pin 1 at 1.5 times other pitch
- pitch from pin 1 to pin 2 = 7.5mm
- pitch for all other pins = 5 mm
- connector is between 6 mm and 6.5 mm high
- connector is between 27.3 mm and 27.7 mm wide
- connector is about 4.2 mm deep
- pins are about 1.1 mm - 1.2 mm square

(measurements are approximate, my digital calipers are a bit cheap, sometimes randomly adding exactly 1/5th of an inch to measurements - these are double and sanity checked)

There is no manufacturer name on either part, just a single letter('P') and a circular symbol that kinda looks like a 6 sided star, divided into 6 segments in a ring. This symbol is also found on one of my NES systems on the power and reset switches, still no company name. Other NES have Mitsumi switches, but they don't seem to be the same company.

Let me know if any other information will help.

Image of the logo:

[image]

Image of connector:

[image]

Left is pin 1.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a power connector judging by size. The pin by itself is probably ground. If you have a close up picture of the circuit board looking downward near the connector I might be able to confirm it and possible tell you what the other pins are for.

Comment: My goal is to find a part that is compatible with this connector to use in a homebrew addon for the NES(for fun and to learn really). Luckily I have the schematics for the Nintendo Famicom, and it's as close as matters to identical. Including every wire on P6. I am planning to update the wiki over at the nesdev.com site once I have the information I'm seeking. For completeness, the pinout is: 1: +13V out(to power switch), 2: +13V in(return from power switch), 3: Reset Switch, 4: Front LED, 5: Common between Reset and LED.

Comment: Your question was to identify the plug.. The plug type shown is a male plug. You need a female to match. Try looking at electronic surplus stores or Amateur Radio flea markets to find components of that type.

Comment: Game consoles often use custom connectors that don't have any commercially available equivalent. You may find something "close enough" that fits if you go through connectors with similar pin spacing from the larger vendors (Samtec, T&E, etc.) I'm confused about the pictures; the first picture was of the power switch housing (with the 'star' logo), and the second picture was of the power connector -- sounds like you just want to find a mating female connector for the power connector only, and the switch isn't really related?